# Active Directory delegating to AWS private hosted zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, active-directory

We have a very strange case going on at our office and I'm not an Active Directory (AD) expert.

We have an internal zone in active directory that we would like to delegate a subdomain out to an AWS private hosted zone in a VPC (connected over a VPN).

VPN is connected, hosts in the VPC are pingable from AD side.

AWS does not allow you to connect to its DNS servers from outside of the VPN but *their* suggestion is to host proxies that will forward the DNS queries to the AWS DNS server.

So we have two boxes that use iptables to forward UDP and TCP 53 to our AWS hosted DNS servers.

From the Active Directory side we can confirm that DNS is indeed being forwarded by using nslookup:

```
nslookup <aws_domain> <dns_proxy_ip>
Server:     <dns_proxy_ip>
Address:    <dns_proxy_ip>#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   <aws_domain>
Address: <correct_ip>
```

We have added the subdomain to active directory as delegated DNS. We cannot use conditional forwarding as then we can't have Active Directory manage part of the DNS.

So... now we see *extremely* strange behavior.

I can query the Active Directory DNS and our AWS domains do *not* show up.

```
nslookup <aws_domain> <active_directory_ip>
Server:     <active_directory_ip>
Address:    <active_directory_ip>#53

** server can't find <aws_domain>: NXDOMAIN
```

However, on *any laptop* that is connected to AD I can query the AWS DNS servers...

```
nslookup <aws_domain> <dns_proxy_ip>
Server:     <dns_proxy_ip>
Address:    <dns_proxy_ip>#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   <aws_domain>
Address: <correct_ip>
```

And now... any laptop (using the regular AD name servers) can see the correct response from AD.

```
nslookup <aws_domain> <active_directory_ip>
Server:     <active_directory_ip>
Address:    <active_directory_ip>#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   <aws_domain>
Address: <correct_ip>
```

It's actually a little disturbing that one laptop (out of hundreds) can affect the whole system.

What I really want to get done though is have Active Directory forward out to my private hosted zone.

Apologies for the long post. I don't know how to make the craziness more succinct.